# Java di module with help of generics and reflection

Tags: java, reflection, dependency-injection

I want to build my own simple di module, for that purpose I created:

```
public interface Factory<T> {
T getInstance();
}
```

and

```
public class DiImpl implments Di{

private Map<Class, Factory> map = new HashMap<>();

@Override
public <T> Factory<T> getFactory(Class<T> type) {
    return (Factory<T>) map.get(type);
}

@Override
public <T> void bind(Class<T> base, Class<? extends T> impl) {
    map.put(base, new Factory<Class<?>>() {
        @Override
        public Class getInstance() {
            return  new Class<?>.newInstance; //here should be new instance of impl class
        }
    });
}
}
```

But this code not pass simple test:

```
interface SimpleService {
....
}

FirstVaraintService implements SimpleService {
...
}

@Test
void test(){
  Di di= new DiImpl();
  di.bind(SimpleService.class, FirstVaraintService.class);       
  Factory<SimpleService> factory = di.getFactory(SimpleService.class);
  assertSame(FirstVaraintService.class, factory.getInstance().getClass());
}
```

compiler returns:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to ... SimpleService
```

I know that, such di structure can be implemented with help of reflection API, but I don't know how to properly use it in this example. How can I change my code to pass the test?

Comment: `Class` represents a class, not an instance. If you want an instance, call `Class.newInstance()`, assuming you have a zero-arg constructor.

Comment: `public <T> void bind(Class<T> base, Class<? extends T> impl)` should be `public <T> void bind(Class<T> base, T impl)`.